# Java Spring boot upload file and send other data as ajax using form submit

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, spring

In my application I need to upload a file  and along with that I need to send one more parameter.
This is my code for the client side.

```
$.ajax({
                url : "/uploadFile",
                type : "POST",

                data: {file_name:new FormData($("#upload-file-form")[0]),"groupName":"xxx"},
                enctype : 'multipart/form-data',
        //      processData : false,
                contentType : false,
                cache : false,

                success : function(data) {
                    if (data == "success") {
                        // alert ("file uploaded successfully")

                        $(".modal-body").html(
                                "<p>File uploaded Successfully</p>")
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');

                    }
                    if (data == "failure") {
                    alert("failure)
                    }
               }
        }
```

My code for server side :

```
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam(value="file_name") MultipartFile file ,@RequestParam(value="groupName") String name){


    System.out.println("file");
    return "success";
}
```

But it says the current request is not a MultiPart Request.
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request

How should I parse both file name and the other parameter? please help

My html form.

```
<form id="upload-file-form">
  <label for="upload-file-input">Upload your CSV file:</label>
  <input id="upload-file-input" type="file" name="uploadfile" accept="*" class="align-right" />
  <br>

  <input type="submit"  id ="groupUpload" value="click here to upload the file" class="btn btn-info" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

See you need to append the values in the `FormData` and it is the only thing needed to be passed. So you can append the extra value which needs to be passed like this:

```
var fd = new FormData($("#upload-file-form")[0]);
    fd.append('groupName', 'xxx');
```

now in the ajax you can simply pass this:

```
data: fd,
processData : false,  // <----required to upload
contentType : false,  // <----required to upload
```

[FormData().append() doc at MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

---

So your code should be like this:

```js
$("#upload-file-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  // <--------stops the form submission
    var fd = new FormData($("#upload-file-form")[0]);
        fd.append('groupName', 'xxx');

    $.ajax({
      url: "/uploadFile",
      type: "POST",
      data: fd,
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
          if (data == "success") {
            $(".modal-body").html("<p>File uploaded Successfully</p>");
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
          } else if (data == "failure") {
            alert("failure)
          }
      }
    });
});
```

[jQuery.ajax() to upload files example @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: Ya I tried  this , this is the error I am getting "There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported ". But my request is POST type ..

Comment: Most probably your form is getting submitted you need to stop the form submission to navigate to the action path.

Comment: you mean event.preventDefault() method?

Comment: Ya I tired that ."This is the error I am getting 400 (Bad Request)". I tried by converting fd to  Json String ,but it says again that it it is not a multipart request. Is there an error in the code for server side?

Comment: can you post your form in your question?